# Insert all records in an Iterable<Object> to a List in java

Tags: java, collections, hadoop, iterator

I have an `Iterable<MyRecord> records` . I iterate over the records like below and add it to a  LinkedList as shown below.

```
for (MyRecord record: records){
    sortedList.addLast(record);
}
```

My iterable has 3 records, all with different values. But in the end although `sortedList` contains 3 records, ALL THREE ARE THE SAME!!!. How come?

When I printed out the memory location, it's the same for all 3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons for this... how do you create your records iterable? Maybe they are the same in the records iterable allready? And... if you have an `Iterable<MyRecord> records` shouldn't the for loop also read the records as "MyRecord" and not "AccountRecord"

Comment: Cant you just use `sortedList.addAll(records)`

Comment: @Chris its actually in hadoop's reduce part. Check it here. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html#reduce(KEYIN, java.lang.Iterable, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context)

Comment: Do you implement the `Iterable` interface yourself? if so your `iterator()` implementation might be wrong. What is the type of records?

Comment: @Chris it's MyRecord actually. sorry.

Comment: See my answer, this is a feature with Hadoop which you have to know about :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your comment reveals the missing link to why this is going wrong. You're using this in a Hadoop mapper or reducer. The trick with Hadoop is that it reuses the objects you're getting in, so that it goes easy on the garbage collector. What you thus have to do is **make a copy** of each of the objects in your source iterable (the `MyRecord`s), and add those to your LinkedList.

Comment: remember you have to make deep copy - if you don't already have a copy constructor, you may want to look into using ReflectionUtils.copy(conf, source, destination) it will handle everything for you - [API Docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ReflectionUtils.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the sortedList contains the same records, which is the last elements in original records, it's possible that the iterator re-use the tmp reference. You need to check the implementation of the 'records'.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is clear and so is the code (also after reading the comments); this may not help, but maybe you can just do, before your add, a contains check like: `if (sortedList.contains(record)) sortedList.add...`

I admit this might not really help (also i don't know if contains checks for element memory location under the hood, as i guess it might only check for element presence in the list using `equals`).

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding items into the list put check :

```
if(sortedList.contains(record))
{
  System.out.println("Record is already available "+record);
}
else
{
 sortedList.addLast(record);
}
```

You will get to know whether the problem is due to same records or because of something else.